# Bios freez on HDD boot(?)

Tags: windows, boot

I have very strange problem. How it started:
laptop was working than I closed the lid, so it hibernated/sleeped, after few hours when I opened it, it didn't work.
Bios is loading without any error, pendrive boot works good, so I can run ubuntu live or windows recovery but when I try to start windows that is installed on HDD it getting very wired. Screen is black but it's backlight works. Laptop works, I can here fans as well. It doesn't react on anything but ctrl+alt+del that resets computer. I tried chkdsk, it found few error and fixed it (nothing realy dangerous), I tried fixmbr etc. 
Nothing has changed. When I try to copy my data by Ubuntu, it doesn't mount partitions because "partition is in unsafe state" - windows is hibernated etc.

It's windows 8.1
Help please

Comment: This could be a failed hard drive. You should take it out and see if you can access if from another computer. Run hard drive tests on another computer to make sure it's not a failing drive. If the drive is healthy and startup repair, nor any other system repair works, then you'll just have to back up everything off it, and reformat the drive reinstalling the OS.

Comment: One more thing, make sure you check in the bios boot menu that it's actually booting off the drive you think it is. Unplug all external devices.

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, try to mount it with the following command in Linux and unmount it:

```
ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sdXY /SOME_MOUNTPOINT
umount /SOME_MOUNTPOINT
```

Then try to reboot to Windows again.